# SQL Group by to include alternate column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
ID,col1,col2,total
1,artist1,artist2,3
2,artist2,artist1,4
```

How do I group columns col1 and col2 and sum the totals so in cases like this I would get:

```
artist1,artist2, 7
```

If two rows contain the same two values but the values lie in opposite columns, i'd still like the sum(total) of both rows, if that makes sense.

Comment: Add some more sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please edit your question, we need more information. What do you require really? select sum(total) from XTABLE group by col1, col2?

Comment: Edited for a little more clarity @abr

Comment: @MelosMojo . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Done @GordonLinoff sorry, I don't use S.O. too often

Answer (score 2):

Most databases have `least()` and `greatest()`.  If so, you can do:

```
select least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2), sum(total)
from t
group by least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2);
```

For databases that do not, it is easy to implement the same logic using `case`.

Answer (score 0):

To filter rows by equality of different(opposite) columns, you should use INNER JOIN of your table on itself and use your opposite columns as the condition for join:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2 from YOURTABLE t1
inner join YOURTABLE t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col2
and t1.col2 = t2.col1;
```

If you don't need row pairs where all artists are the same in all columns ("artist1" is in col1 and col2 too and in both rows), then you need to filter out these cases:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2 from YOURTABLE t1
inner join YOURTABLE t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col2
and t1.col2 = t2.col1
and t1.col1 <> t1.col2;
```

After selecting needed rows, you can SUM their total. You will get the desired result:

```
select sum(t1.total) from YOURTABLE t1
inner join YOURTABLE t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col2
and t1.col2 = t2.col1
and t1.col1 <> t1.col2;
```

If you need to show artist names with this total, you should specify which artist (from first row or second row or what?) should be shown. You didn't specified any conditions for this. You can use MIN and MAX functions or LEAST and GREATEST or any other multi-row function. Here is the example:

```
select min(t1.col1), max(t1.col2), sum(t1.total) from YOURTABLE t1
inner join YOURTABLE t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col2
and t1.col2 = t2.col1
and t1.col1 <> t1.col2;
```

Hope this helps!